# React Native Disable DrawerNavigator for particular screen

Tags: react-native

I want to Disable DrawerNavigator for particular screen either swipe over screen or DrawerOpen request.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `drawerLockMode` in your screen:

```
  static navigationOptions = () => ({
    drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed'
  })
```

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html#a-drawer-has-a-stack-inside-of-it-and-you-want-to-lock-the-drawer-on-certain-screens